# ElasticSearch 5.1 Fielddata is disabled in text field by default [ERROR: trying to use aggregation on field]

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, aggregation

Having this field in my mapping

```
"answer": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
```

i try to execute this aggregation

```
"aggs": {
"answer": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "answer"
  }
},
```

but i get this error

```
"type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [answer] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory."
```

Do i have to change my mapping or am i using the wrong aggregation ? (just updated from 2.x to 5.1)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You need to aggregate on the `keyword` sub-field, like this:

```
"aggs": {
"answer": {
  "terms": {
    "field": "answer.keyword"
  }
},
```

That will work.

Answer (score 2):

In Aggregation, just add keyword to answer.It worked for me. For text fields we need to add keyword.
    "field": "answer.keyword"

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @Val's answer, you can also set the `fielddata` to true during your mapping itself:

```
"answer": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true, <-- add this line
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",                
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      },
```

Comment: I'm not certain the [`keyword` type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html) accepts any `fielddata` setting actually, like the `text` type does.

Comment: As per the exception (`Set fielddata=true on [answer]`), I thought the issue was from the `answer` in the mapping provided.

Comment: That's because he aggregated on `answer`, but he's better off aggregating on `answer.keyword` since he has that field.