# Elasticsearch: can I avoid enabling fielddata on text fields?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I'm trying to get the latest records, grouped by the field `groupId`, which is a String like *"group_a"*.

I followed the accepted **answer of** [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29016271/how-to-get-latest-values-for-each-group-with-an-elasticsearch-query), but I've got the following **error** message:

> Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [your_field_name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory.

In the [Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/fielddata.html) is written:

> Before you enable fielddata, consider why you are using a text field for aggregations, sorting, or in a script. **It usually doesn’t make sense** to do so.

I'm using a text field, because `groupId` is a String. **Does it make sense** to set `fielddata: true` if I want to group by it?

Or **are there alternatives?**

Using `"field": "groupId.keyword"` ([suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41485058/elasticsearch-5-1-fielddata-is-disabled-in-text-field-by-default-error-trying)) didn't work for me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggest answer with .keyword is the correct one.

```
{
    "aggs": {
        "group": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "groupId.raw"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "group_docs": {
                    "top_hits": {
                        "size": 1,
                        "sort": [
                            {
                                "timestamp (or wathever you want to sort)": {
                                    "order": "desc"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with a mapping like that:

```
       "groupId": {
           "type": "text",
           "fields": {
              "raw": {
                 "type": "keyword"
              }
           }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I adjusted the mapping, but still no success. Could you please provide me the URL you would use? I'm trying `GET /myindex/_search`. `?search_type=count`, as seen in the other solution, is deprecated.

Comment: Try: POST myindex/_search?pretty